# Calculus - Integrals concepts

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I am starting to learn Calculus at school and I covered all the concepts about derivatives (Correct me if I am wrong, but a derivative is a function which gives us the slope of a function on a certain point, it has many practical applications since we can find the maximum or minimum point much faster). Now I want to dive into Integrals. I know that a Definite Integral is simply a function that returns the area below a graph between 2 points, right? And I know that an Indefinite Integral or also called Antiderivative takes a derivative and returns the possible function that originated that derivative in the first place. So far, so good...

My question: Why do all Definite Integrals take an Indefinite Integral as an argument? I mean, we have to Antiderivative first and afterwards, we put this in the Definite Integral... Is that possible that I just put a function as an argument? Or I will always have to Antiderivative to Integrate? If so, why?

One more question: Differential calculus is a branch and Integral Calculus is another completely different, right? if not, how do they integrate each other?

Sorry if I haven't made myself clear, bear with me because I am still learning

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So far I haven't understood this theorem, would you be willing to provide me some material (video, article)? I would appreciate if the material wasn't too technical because I am not a real mathematician, I simply like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One terminology-related comment I'll add is that the integral doesn't tell you the area; it tells you the **signed area** (because if the function is negative in a certain region, then its integral will be negative too, so we interpret that as "negative area").

You're right about derivatives. If $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a given function, then the derivative $f' : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is another function such that at every point $a \in \Bbb{R}$, $f'(a)$ is a number, which can be geometrically interpreted as the slope of the tangent line to the graph of the function $f$, at the point $(a,f(a)).$

Anti-differentiation is just a process for "undoing" the differentiation. (The term anti-differentiation is really the most appropriate term here). So far this has nothing to do with integrals!

When first learning about integration, I firmly believe that there should be no mention of "indefinite integrals". The first thing you should learn about integration is the so called "definite integrals". So, given a function $f$, and an interval $[a,b]$, the definite integral is denoted by the symbol
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f.
\end{equation}

**This is a number**, and it is often defined using Riemann sums, and geometrically, this tells you the signed area bounded by the graph of the function $f$, and the horizontal axis between $[a,b]$. You asked about the argument of the definite integral. Well, to calculate a definite integral all you need to know is the function $f$ whose integral you want to calculate, and the endpoints $a$ and $b$. This is exactly what the notation $\int_a^b f$ suggests. So, the argument of a definite integral is the function $f$ which you wish to integrate, along with the endpoints $a$ and $b$. That's it. At this point, there should be no more talk about antiderivatives or indefinite integrals or anything else.

> Once again, I highlight this just to make it abundantly clear: to define definite integrals, all you need is the function $f$, and the two endpoints $a$, and $b$. Nothing more than that!

Up until this point, differentiation, anti-differentiation and integration are all separate things! So far there is no relationship between them at all. Differentiation talks about slopes of functions, while integration talks about signed area bounded by graphs of functions. They are so separate that computing definite integrals like $\int_a^b t^4 \, dt$ or $\int_0^{2\pi} \cos t \, dt$ is a nightmare if you only use the Riemann sums definition. **The connection between these concepts comes only AFTER** you prove the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. (that's why it's called Fundamental) It says two things (I omit technical hypotheses of the theorems)

- If we are given a nice enough function $f$, and we define a new function $F$ by the rule $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_a^x f$, then the derivative of $F$ is calculated by the formula $F'(x) = f(x)$.
- Suppose we are given a nice enough function $f$. If $g$ is a function such that $g' =f$, then, to compute the definite integral $\displaystyle \int_a^b f$, all we need to do is use the formula
  \begin{equation}
  \int_a^b f = g(b) - g(a)
  \end{equation}

In simple terms, the first part of the theorem says that every nice function **has** an anti-derivative. So, the first part, is what we might call an "existence" theorem for anti-derivatives. Said differently, integrating a function $f$, with a varying upper limit $x$, defines a new function $F$, such that $F' = f$. It is in this sense that "integration undoes differentiation".

For example, take $f(t) = e^{t^2}$. There is no elementary formula for its anti-derivative in terms of algebraic operations, trigonometric functions, exponential/logarthims. However, the theorem states that an anti-derivaive for $f$ **exists**, namely the function $F$ defined by
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \int_0^x f = \int_0^{x} e^{t^2} \, dt
\end{equation} 
(there is no further simplification we can make for $F$, but atleast this is a formula for an anti-derivative)

The second part of the theorem is a computational recipe. It tells us a nice method for computing definite integrals. For example, if $f(t) = t^4$, then the first part of the theorem says that the function $F$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
F(x) = \int_a^x f
\end{equation}
is an anti-derivative, so
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f = F(b) - F(a) = \int_a^b f - \int_a^a f = \int_a^b f - 0 = \int_a^b f
\end{equation}
Ouch! This wasn't very helpful. So, although the theorem is true, using $F$ as the antiderivative wasn't very helpful, because all we did was say $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b f$. Fortunately, we know of another function which is an anti-derivative of $f$. Namely, 
\begin{equation}
g(x) = \dfrac{x^5}{5}
\end{equation}
By basic rules of derivatives, you can show that $g' = f$. This is indeed very useful, because now we can say:
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f = g(b) - g(a) = \dfrac{b^4}{4} - \dfrac{a^4}{4},
\end{equation}
which is a nice formula. Notice how easy this was; we just had to find a nice formula for the anti-derivative rather than computing Riemann sums, and limits etc.

---

It is only after we prove this theorem that the two concepts of differentiation and integration can be linked! So, to summarize:

**Before Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:**

- Differentiation, anti-differentiation, integration are all separate concepts!
- Computing derivatives is (usually) easy, which calculating integrals is (usually) difficult. Integrals are difficult, because their very definitions are very technical and involved; one needs to do calculate Riemann sums, then take a complicated limit.
- Anti-differentiation is not that interesting (this is a slight exaggeration but it helps make the point)

**After Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:**

- Derivatives are still easy.
- Calculating integrals becomes much easier, and now anti-differentiation is extremely useful, because to calculate $\int_a^b f$, rather than working with Riemann sums and limits, all we have to do is anti-differentiate $f$, and find a function $g$ such that $g'=f$. Then, $\int_a^b f = g(b) - g(a)$.

Hence, anti-differentiation, is a **tool** which allows us to compute integrals "easily" (this is often still difficult because finding anti-derivatives is tough, but atleast now it is easier than before FTC).

---

I think often, people do not appreciate the significance of the FTC because they have been taught integration poorly. They might think that
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f
\end{equation}
is **defined** as $g(b) - g(a)$, where $g$ is a function satisfying $g' = f$, so the second part of the theorem seems completely redundant. This is simply incorrect; this is NOT how integrals are defined... they are defined using Riemann sums.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer, you are a lifesaver! That is the answer I was looking for! Thank you very much, thanks to you now I don't lack in concepts anymore