# What are the implications of the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus

Can someone explain to me the implications of FTC in word? I was incorrectly taught that integration is DEFINED as the reverse of differentiation, which is stuck in my head instead of the limit of the sum. Consequently, I just naturally Think of finding the “integral” as computing what I now know as an “anti-derivative” ( never introduced to that term in my education) and cannot really grasp FTC properly.

*I would really like if someone could boil it down into **words**, in addition to the theorem in mathematical notation. I just see fancy notation in all the answers, which i understand perfectly, but cannot put into words in my mind without writing everything down*

And what are F(x), f(x) and f(t) representing in the 2 different parts of FTC?

Comment: See [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: The antiderivate is not unique, only upto addition of a constant. But if you differentiate any antiderivate, you will return to your original function.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH Part of your confusion might just be the terminology. 'Antiderivative' is just another term for indefinite integral. Indefinite integration is *defined* to be the opposite of differentiation. Definite integration, on the other hand, is *defined* to be the area under the curve. The FTC tells us that we can work out the area under the curve using the indefinite integral. This is actually a very interesting result that isn't trivial. It's not trivial because we define definite integrals in terms of areas—not in terms of indefinite integrals.

Comment: Take a look at this [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3273123/568204) of mine where I try to clearly stress the difference between differentiation, anti-differentiation (more commonly called indefinite integrals), and integration (definite), and how the Fundamental theorem of calculus comes into the whole picture.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH This important and interesting result—that the area under the curve is somehow linked to the indefinite integral—is the crux of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: @peek-a-boo i read your answer and it has really cleared up a lot. Can you tell me if  have understood this correctly? 
The first part of the FTC says that if A(x) is the DEFINITE integral or net area function( i know definite integrals arent just about area but this helps me remember) of f up till some point “x”, then the derivative of that function, A’(x), is f itself. What this means that, since every continuous function has an area under it, every function must have an derivative. No other use for this part.

Comment: And the second part says that to compute the definite integral/ net area under f, instead of Doing it from first principles by finding the limit Of the reimann sum, we can just find find the antiderivative. Is this correct? Also, the usual notation of FTC part 1, where derivative Os w.r.t x but f is a function of t, is really confusing me

Comment: most of what you said is correct, but "every function must have an derivative" is very wrong. Perhaps you meant to say something like "the 'area' integral function $x \mapsto A(x)$ of a continuous function $f$ is differentiable"?

Comment: Im sorry, i missed the “anti-“ part. Thats why i used “an’ and not “a”. Would that he correct?

Answer (score 2):

In plain English, the fundamental theorem of calculus states that the rate of change of the area under the curve of a function at any point is the value of the function at that point.

Indeed, informally speaking, if you consider the area under the curve of a function from $a$ to $x$ where $a$ is fixed and $x$ is gradually "moving" to the right, you can see that the *increase* in the area under this curve as you go from $x$ to $x+dx$ is the area of the very thin rectangle with base $dx$ and height, approximately, $f(x)$. This area is $f(x)dx$ and so the rate of change of the area under the curve at $x$ is $$f(x)dx/dx = f(x)$$.

Comment: Im sorry for this stupid question but why does f have to be a function of t? Why cant both A( the definite integral/area function) be both functions of x?

Comment: t is the independent variable, and you are integrating from a, a fixed point, to t=x, a variable point. This area will be a function of x - as x increases the area will increase. You are interested in the rate of change of the area under the curve of f(t) from t=a to t=x. This rate at any point t=x is given by f(x).

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot. One last thing,  could you elaborate on the condition of continuity? Why does the function have to be continuous? 1/x isnt continuous and its anti derivative does exist ( lnx )

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH As strange as it may sound, $1/x$ is continuous. Please look it up.

Comment: 1/x is continuous in (0,infinity). In my answer, I assumed that the height of the thin rectangle is f(x). I need f(x) to be continuous to make this assumption.

Comment: 1/x is continuous in (0,infinity). In my answer, I assumed that the height of the thin rectangle is f(x). I need f(x) to be continuous to make this assumption. The point is that if f(x) is continuous then it can't vary too much if the change in the independent variable is very small. In the thin rectangle the variation in the independent variable is infinitesimal. So I can assume that the height of the rectangle is more or less f(x).

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks a lot